# How to access group keys during aggregation in pandas groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

Is there a way to access the group keys from inside the aggregation functions? For example we have the following dataframe:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
        'score' : [2,2,3,3,3],
        'age' : [17,23,18,12,15]
    })
>>> df
   score  age
0      2   17
1      2   23
2      3   18
3      3   12
4      3   15
```

And do something like

```
df.groupby('score').agg(
    score_age = ('age', lambda x: x.groupkey + sum(x))
)
```

to get

```
       score_age
score           
2             42
3             48
```

Obviously `x.groupkey` does not work. What's the right syntax to access it? I can't seem to find it anywhere. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df1 = df.groupby('score').agg(score_age = ('age', lambda x: x.name + x.sum()))
print (df1)
       score_age
score           
2             42
3             48
```

Comment: Ohh it indeed worked! But how come if I remove `x.sum()`, I'm getting values of `'age'`  and not `2` and `3`?

Comment: @Loqz - not idea - but hack is `df.groupby('score').agg(score_age = ('age', lambda x: x.name + 0))`

Comment: are you able to find a way without hacking it with "+ 0"? What if the value is not an number? Is there a general way to access the key?

Comment: @Loqz - It is `x.name`, so use only `lambda x: x.name`

Comment: `x.name` doesn't work. if you use that, the output will be the word "age" instead of its actual numeric values

Comment: @Loqz - You are right, not so easy. Can you check `df.set_index('score').groupby('score').agg(score_age = ('age', lambda x: x.keys()[0]))` ?

Comment: wow, what a hack! But it works, thanks!